# Excel window goes blank

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Excel 2016 on Windows 10. Occasionally, Excel's window will go blank with the exception of the title bar, the selected cell's font (in the ribbon), and several boxes containing the Paste icon, the characters (Ctrl) and a down arrow, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

The windows stay in this state for many seconds or even a few minutes before returning to normal. Some more information I have been able to gather:

- This sometimes happens two or three times in a day, but more often I go several weeks and then have a single occurrence.
- I can think of nothing special that happened at the time of the problem.
- If I have multiple Excel windows open, they all go blank and recover at the same time.
- Although the example in the screenshot is an xlsm file, the problem is not limited to files with macros, it happens with xlsx files as well.
- When the problem is happening, if I click the Windows button (the former Start button at the bottom left of the screen), the Excel windows appear to be restored, but if I try to interact with them, they immediately go blank again.

Does anyone know how to prevent this, or even any suggestions on how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: To start troubleshooting, on the Details tab in Task Manager, right-click the Excel.exe process and click **Analyze Wait Chain**. That should give you an idea of what resource is blocking Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the application title bar indicates, the program has stopped responding. The usual culprit is either the excel file being very large or doing a lot of processing. Second culprit would be something else that is eating up a lot of CPU/memory. Third culprit could be a funky Office install. When the issue is happening you can open Task Manager to check on some things. Start notes on if a certain Excel file is always open when the issue happens as it could be corrupt